# Android start Fragment putString

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

i wrote code withc can to start new fragment.this is a source

```
Fragmen1 newFragment = new Fragmen1 ();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
```

not i want to use putExtra to put some String and show in my Fragmen1  fragment
P.s
in activity i know how to use putExtra,but fragment i never use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to pass a bundle:

```
Fragmen1 newFragment = new Fragmen1();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("my_string","fragmentQ");
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

To receive the bundle:

```
String str = getArguments().getString("my_string");
```

It is always better to check if getArguments() is null first.

Comment: thank and how i can  recive "my_string" in Fragmen1 fragment?